# How to edit a WFS layer with leaflet draw

Tags: leaflet, jquery, leaflet-draw

I have spend more than 4 hours trying to figure out how I can do this.
I use Leaflet and Leaflet Draw in order to draw news features on my map.

Now I want to be able to edit features of an existing WFS layer (coming from geoserver).

I have searched a lot all around internet and I can not find a clear example of how to make my WFS layer editable.

This is what I do based on the example from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ddproxy/suL12z93/3/):

```
// intialize the drawItems and add it to the map 
var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
 map_add.addLayer(drawnItems);
// initialize the controls  (only editing) and add it to the map
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
          draw: {
              position: 'topleft'
          },
          edit: {
              featureGroup: drawnItems,
              edit: true
              }
          }
      });
map_add.addControl(drawControl);

url_string = "thats my url"
// make wfs request and add the layer in the drawItems 
var geojson = $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
          url: url_string,
          success: function (response) {
             drawnItems.addLayer(L.geoJson(response));
          }
        });
```

The layer is displayed on the map. But when I click the edit button (of the leaflet draw plugin) I get a:

```
      Cannot read property 'enable' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?
Please advise! 
If I follow the example in the link I provided it works. But the guy there he uses data inline with his code. I need to use the layer from the WFS request.

Comment: I forgot to mention it, it worked for me because I inserted the drawnItems.addLayer(e.target); inside onEachFeature function, that's why I don't get the undefined error

Comment: great. I will check this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to the tips you send me from stackoverflow I managed to make the features editable.

Now for the WFS layer part, I think that you'll have to construct the WFS-T query by yourself as [here](https://github.com/Georepublic/leaflet-wfs/blob/master/index.html#L242) in the Georepublic example or as in my case switch to a server side language like php or use Node.js and store directly to the database if you have one.

I almost gave up on Leaflet when I found out that there isn't much support for WFS-T, and that you'll have to code everything yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the WFS-T request is not really so complicated. You actually can execute it using a php or python script and the CURL requests library (or Requests library of python). Geoserver supports WFS-T. On the left sidebar there is a Demo section where you can see how your XML needs to be structured.

Comment: that's exactly what made me change my mind on using WFS-T, in OL3 there is already the formatWFS() which makes it easy but in leaflet one have to structure the WFS-T request, and laziness took over me ;)